# Open automate flow with bixby key

Tags: bixby, voice-recording

I made an automate flow to start record in until I switch screen off, I made it to be my personal quick recorder.

I want to use bixby key to trigger the flow when I click it but I can't do it.

What I tried so far..

I used an app called 'Home Launcher' I made it to open the flow when I long press home key instead of google assistant. But when I try bixby key it open the launcher and then I have to click on the flow.

What I want..

An app to open a short cut without any interface when I open the app for the first time it make me choose what to open and then every time I click the app it open the flow immediately.

What the use of that..

When I want to record a fast note I open the phone and click bixby key then automate will start recording when I done I lock the phone to make the flow stop and save the voice note.

Here is the flow I use..

[My automate flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYZW2.jpg)

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it.

The simple answer.

1. I used an app called Mute, all it does is to mute phone.
2. Made bixby key open the Mute app.
3. Made a flow to watch when phone is mute to start recording.
4. Made a fork in the flow to watch when phone is unmutes to stop and save the recorded note.

How it works.

1. When I press bixby key it mute phone,
2. Then automate start record,
3. When I press bixby key again the phone is unmuted,
4. Automate stop recording.

And finally I made my samsung flagship a very assume voice note recorder.

Thanks for all who tried to help.

Good luck everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are asking about can only be addressed by the developer of the app since, once the Bixby button is clicked per your settings, the app is launched and is responsible for the rest of your experience.

The app developer would need to do one of the following two things in order to achieve your desired flow:

1. You would need to request the app developer to implement the behavior you want (run the flow you've defined in your instance of the app)

OR

2. The app developer would need to develop a Bixby capsule that would open the app and run the flow you've defined with an utterance. This utterance could then be set as a Quick Command to be triggered when you click the Bixby button once or twice depending on your settings.

Comment: Thanks ameya for your answer. I'll try to contact the developer.. bit isn't there and app that could open shortcuts, or star recording immediately when I click it and stop when re click.

Comment: Glad to help! I'm sure there are apps that start a functionality immediately upon startup but that functionality is governed solely by the app developer. Additionally, the Bixby button simply acts as an "On" button for the functionality you define via the button settings menu. It won't be able to do the "Stop" action on a second click.

Comment: I made the flow stop once I turn off the screen so I don't need to press bixby button again.